# Reactive() in shiny R server not working?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm having a bit of trouble with reactive() in my shiny server.

Here's my overall code right now:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

DX <- unique(newDT$dx.x)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    h3('Procedure Flow for Low Back Pain FY 16-17'),
    column(12,fluidRow(column(3, inputPanel(
            selectInput("dx", label = "Diagnosis:",
              choices = DX, selected = "LBP")
                  ))
           )),
    lapply(unique(newDT$pat), function(patient) {
      fluidRow(column(1, tags$p(patient)), 
               column(11, lapply(unique(newDT[pat == patient]$clinic), 
                  function(clinic){
                    fluidRow(column(1, tags$p(clinic)),
                             column(10, plotOutput(outputId = paste(patient, clinic), height = "100%")))
                  })))

    })
  ),

  server <- function(input, output) {

    newDT2 <- reactive({
      newDT[dx.x == input$dx,]
    })

    x <- max(newDT2()$dat) + 0.5
    #observe({print(x)})

    for (patt in unique(newDT2()$pat)) { local({
      patient <- patt
      for (clinic in unique(newDT2()[pat==patient]$clinic)) {local({
        c <- clinic
        ht <- 50*length(unique(newDT2()[pat == patient & clinic == c]$clinic2))
        wd <- 225*x
        output[[paste(patient,c )]] <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(newDT2()[pat == patient & clinic == c], 
               aes(x = dat, y = clinic2)) +
          geom_tile(aes(fill = type)) +
          geom_text(aes(label = stringr::str_wrap(Proc, width = 50))) +
            #theme_void() +
            theme(legend.position = "none",
                  plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"),
                  panel.spacing = unit(2, "cm")) +
            #expand_limits(x = 0.5) +
            xlim(c(0.5, x)) +
            theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                 axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                 axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                 axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                 axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                 panel.border = element_blank())
      }, height = ht, width = wd)


    })
      }
    })
    }
  }
  )
```

I keep getting an error message "Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)"
and I really don't understand why, since my data is in reactive().

TIA!

Comment: The error is actually quite informative (which is rare in R). You're trying to access reactive values outside a reactive context. `observe()` `reactive()` and render functions are examples of reactive contexts. You need to define x as `reactive()`. Same goes for the for loop - you're referring to `newDT2()` which is reactive so you need to do it inside a reactive context like an observe. If you don't understand it and need a tutorial on this topic, you can read my "reactivity 101" tutorial https://deanattali.com/blog/building-shiny-apps-tutorial/#10-reactivity-101

Comment: oh, that works. Thank you so much!! was very helpful